# Create a custom function with the insert statement in SQLite3 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 in iOS and I would like to know if you can do this:

```
insert into MyTableUsers values ('test', md5('some_pass'))
```

In SQLite3, you can create a custom function for, for example, MD5. But only by using a select statement:

`select md5('some_string')` , it will return the result of the MD5 function by calling your MD5 implementation.

But how can I do that with just an Insert statement ?

Comment: Don't implement cryptographic algorithms yourself; use whatever professional libraries or built-in cryptography is available.

Comment: Hi Barth, it is an example, i need to exec a script file directly import users data with md5 password or other crypto algorithm.

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. Your "insert" statement should look like `insert into MyTableUsers values (?, ?)`. Then you bind the values into the prepared statement. This is much safer. And it also eliminates the need for the custom SQL function since you can use a native function call for the value.

Answer (score 0):

it's works for insert statement like select with FMDB makeFunctionNamed.